# How can I log in in Windows 11 Home without MS account?

Tags: privacy, windows-11

I want to see how Windows 11 works before upgrading but I hate logging in with a microsoft account. This is because of privacy reasons. How can I create a local account instead of a microsoft account?

(I know there is an official way using Windows 11 Pro but I don't have the money for that)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are asked to connect to the internet, just connect your ethernet cable, then click "continue". While its checking for updates, immediately unplug the ethernet cable, and let it do its thing. After the reboot, it will let you create a local account.

Comment: You have tested this method with Windows 11 Home.  According to my extensive research this shouldn’t work on Home editions of either Windows 10 21H1+ nor Windows 11 21H2.

Comment: It is indeed not an official way, but it works from what I tested (with the official iso)

Answer (score 0):

For you to log in in Windows 11 Home without MS account? follow this steps below

1. Run the installation process as usual, and press Shift+F10 when it asks for an
   internet connection.
2. Type taskmgr and press the Enter button.
3. Click on the More details button find out the Network Connection Flow process.
4. Click it and select End task button.
5. Close all windows and enter your name and password to continue

This is all you need to [login Windows 11 Home without MS account](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-install-windows-11-home-without-microsoft-account).